# What does locking a password using `passwd -l` mean?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

It is possible to lock a password using

```
$ passwd -l john
```

But what does that actually mean to lock a password?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`man` page for `passwd`:

> `-l, --lock`
> Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a password by changing it to a value which matches no possible
> encrypted value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning of the password).

Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an
SSH key). To disable the account, administrators should use usermod --expiredate 1 (this set the account's expire date to Jan
2, 1970).
Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their password.

Comment: I didn't know `man` had so much more info. I just used `passwd --help`